# Counter localStorage

Tags: javascript, counter

I would like to add the localStorage in this code. Unfortunately I'm not very good at js.

```
function animateValue(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var current = obj.innerHTML;

  setInterval(function() {
    obj.innerHTML = current--;
  }, 5000);
}

animateValue('value');
```

I tried to add some lines found on https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage but I can't make it work. How can I?

Comment: how do you want to set localStorage?

Comment: generally its `localStorage.setItem('something', 'value');` and if you want to get the `value` its `localStorage.getItem('something');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set and get from localStroage as given below.

```
function animateValue(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var counter = getLocalStoregaValue();
  var current = counter ? +counter : obj.innerHTML;
  obj.innerHTML = current;
  
  setInterval(function() {
    var counter = current--;
    obj.innerHTML = counter;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
  }, 5000);
}

function getLocalStoregaValue() {
  return localStorage.getItem('counter');
}

animateValue('value');
```

You can user `getLocalStoregaValue` method anywhere in your js to get counter value.

Comment: I tried without success. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/7k6uevrd/

Comment: Edited my answer. : https://jsfiddle.net/n0mhf61y/1/

Comment: it still refreshes :(

Comment: edited answer here too. please approve my answer and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `setInterval` you can add the counter to `localStorage` (I'm assuming this is what you want to do).

```
setInterval(function(){
  obj.innerHTML = current--;
  localStorage.setItem('counter', current--);
},5000);
```

Then to get that value (as a number):

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
```

Comment: Shouldn't the value also be of type string? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Only if it's an object

Comment: Though, with arrays, the values can be stored but they can't be parsed without some `.split()` `.join()` trickery

Comment: So far I have always saved this as JSON. Without .split() and .join() trickery ...

Comment: I didn't know stringify and parse worked with arrays. That's definitely better than split/join

Comment: I did several tests but none works as I would like. The counter is always refreshed :(
https://jsfiddle.net/pys9bz0g/